# equivalent to oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

In mysql to grant all privileges to user I use this

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'newuser'@'%';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

In oracle what is the equivalent of that ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.6.2.1/ref/rrefsqljgrant.html

Comment: @jophab - that's for JavaDB, not Oracle RDBMS.

Comment: This can help you : https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/120973/grant-all-privileges-of-all-tables-in-database-to-a-user

Answer (score 0):

Create a user with their username and password

```
CREATE USER username IDENTIFIED BY password;
```

Grant them all permisions

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES TO username;
```

Comment: what about i.p address ?